# Understanding of Rails 4's strong parameters

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, strong-parameters

I'm totally new to Rails and I'm playing with it. Now I'm trying to understand the `strong parameter` feature introduced in Rails 4. Below is my code:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  def index
  end

  def show
  end

  def create
    p = Post.new(create_post_params)
    p.save

    redirect_to p
  end

  def new
  end

  private

  def create_post_params
    params.require(:post).permit :title, :body
  end
end
```

Beside the controller, I also have a Post model with a `title` and a `body`. My question is what is this **:post** thing in `params.require(:post).permit :title, :body`? I write it as **:post**, is it because I'm currently inside the `PostsController`? Or I'm reading the properties of a `Post`?

---

## Edit

Based on gdpelican's answer, if my `new.html.erb` is like this:

```
<h1>Create a post</h1>
<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :title %>
    <%= f.text_field :title, class: "form-control" %>
    <p class="help-block">Please type the title of the post</>
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <%= f.label :body %>
    <%= f.text_area :body, class: "form-control", rows: 5 %>
    <p class="help-block">Please type the body of the post</>
  </div>

  <%= f.submit class: "btn btn-primary" %>

<% end %>
```

It's the **:post** part in `<%= form_for :post, url: posts_path do |f| %>` determines that I should use **:post** in `params.require(:post).permit :title, :body`, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your parameters (typically) look like this

```
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"...", "post"=>{"title"=>"My title", "body" =>"Body of my Post"}}
```

When you require a specific key from the parameters (for example post) Rails will throw an error if the hash it was passed doesn't have `"post"=>{....}`, then once it passes that check it permits the allowed keys and returns **only** the parameters nested under "post" hash allowed.  To copy the api docs examples

```
params = ActionController::Parameters.new({
  person: {
    name: 'Francesco',
    age:  22,
    role: 'admin'
  }
})

params.require(:person).permit(:name, :age)
=>{"name"=>"Francesco", "age"=>22}
```

So after your strong params check, the return is a hash of `:post` parameters that you have allowed.

EDIT:  To answer your second question.

That is one way of thinking about it.  Your form syntax (`form_for :post`) is creating the `post` hash with the attributes nested inside, and sending it as part of the overall parameters hash.  And your `params.require(:post)` is taking the entire params, and finding only the hash key it wants (`post`) and then permitting the keys that are inside the post hash.

Answer (score 2):

It is the name of the JSON wrapper of your form values.

The form will typically wrap the form parameters like so:

```
{
  post: {
    title: "Title",
    body:  "Body",
  }
}
```

When using something like `form_for @post`

In essence, `params.require(:post).permit(:title, :body)` is saying two things:

1. my parameters must have a :post attribute
2. the :post attribute may only have a title and a body parameters, and nothing else.

### UPDATE

The parameters in `form_for` are what affect how your parameters are wrapped.

Generally, the name of the controller matches the name of the form parameters, so in most instances it's a safe assumption that a 'BooksController' will accept form parameters in a 'book' field.